# I am trying to use a LM324 4 channel opamp to create RGB color fading

Tags: rgb

Based on this design 
http://www.moddingtech.de/tutorials/44-lichteffekte/66-led-fader.html 
The LM324 has 4 opamps, this design is only using 2.

In the design one opamp is the timing circuit and the other creates the fade.

I am trying to get a phase shift on the individual outputs to drive pnp transistors that control the colors to the 4 pin RGBs.

Has anyone tried this?

I would like to achieve a slow color fade of a minimum 5 seconds per shift.

Comment: If there is a more effective way to slow color fade that does not use a microcontroller I am open to suggestions? I already have the LEDs.

Comment: I haven't done this, but intend to in the future, and wish to offer you some advise to consider, which is basically to do it with a microcontroller. The investment to begin coding and working with single chip MCUs (such as the many PIC offerings from Microchip.com) is not too bad these days, and then there are complete postage stamp sized single board computers based on various MCUs, which you can learn to program with free software. I too will often do things things like this with op-amps. But later when I want to change the behavior, there's much more freedom with coded MCUs.

Comment: You could also drive two more PNP transistors from the same LM324 then all colour LEDs would be controlled together but the main problem will be that of colour matching in the fade - due to differences in light outputs as they fade the colour will alter.

Comment: 'phase shift'? 'color fade'? what _exactly_ do you want to do?

Comment: Color fade each leg of the RGB to mix up the colors. I am trying to build this project but with color fading http://www.instructables.com/id/Enchanted-Forest-Mushroom-Lights/

Answer (score 1):

This is a positive feedback Relaxation oscillator that drives one array only. i.e. it fades brightness in linear mode (although our eyes are logarithmic) and Red turns on first and off last but does not fade between colours.

It creates a variable triangle wave frequency biased from 9V to to give 0-30mA peak linear triangle current with series R to adjust colour brightness since green tends to be brighter but RED is 2.1 while B/G are 3.1V

You can adjust the pot or any part of the design using the mouse. (Ctrl+click to stretch parts, or drag around or edit values.... and more in this [***Falstad Java simulator***](http://www.falstad.com/circuit-java/#%24+0+0.005+16.817414165184545+50+5.0+43%0Aa+368+224+496+224+0+7.5+1.5+1000000.0%0Aa+192+224+64+224+0+7.5+1.5+1000000.0%0Aw+64+224+64+176+0%0Aw+272+208+192+208+0%0Aw+64+96+192+96+0%0Aw+192+240+192+176+0%0Aw+544+256+544+304+0%0Aw+336+240+336+208+0%0Aw+496+224+496+192+0%0Aw+336+240+368+240+0%0Aw+416+176+368+176+0%0Aw+368+208+368+176+0%0Aw+416+176+416+96+0%0Aw+496+192+496+96+0%0Ac+416+96+496+96+0+2.2E-5+0.05445154214656167%0A174+192+96+288+96+0+1000000.0+0.6584000000000001+1M+Pot%0Aw+240+80+240+64+0%0Aw+240+64+192+64+0%0Aw+192+96+192+64+0%0Aw+288+96+416+96+0%0Ar+64+176+192+176+0+100000.0%0Aw+192+96+192+128+0%0Aw+64+176+64+96+0%0Aw+272+208+336+208+0%0Ar+272+208+272+160+0+100000.0%0Ar+272+208+272+256+0+100000.0%0AR+272+160+272+128+0+0+40.0+9.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ag+272+256+272+272+0%0At+496+224+544+224+0+1+-4.5544959971865895+0.6439635195403959+100.0%0AR+544+208+544+160+0+0+40.0+9.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ar+544+336+544+368+0+330.0%0Ar+592+336+592+368+0+220.0%0Ar+496+336+496+368+0+330.0%0Aw+496+368+544+368+0%0Aw+544+368+592+368+0%0Ag+544+368+544+384+0%0A162+496+304+496+336+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+544+304+544+336+1+3.1+0.0+1.0+0.0%0A162+592+304+592+336+1+3.1+0.0+0.0+1.0%0Aw+496+304+544+304+0%0Aw+544+304+592+304+0%0Aw+544+240+544+256+0%0Ar+496+288+192+288+0+47000.0%0Aw+192+288+192+240+0%0Aw+496+288+496+224+0%0Ax+220+125+252+131+0+24+1M%0Ax+117+277+147+283+0+24+U1%0Ax+424+273+454+279+0+24+U2%0Ax+536+429+652+432+0+10+Tony+Stewart++30-9-2016%0Ao+13+64+0+35+10.0+9.765625E-5+0+-1+U2+out%0Ao+6+64+0+33+5.0+0.05+1+-1+Transistor+current%0A)

[image]

minor change to slow down effect with 1M pot. or increase C.

Comment: you are very welcome (+1)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDsqa7VkfW8 this is closer. With a duplicate circuit with the other 2 opamps and a mix of the RGB pins I will get a nice mix I think. I am toooo low level to upvote yet :(

Comment: you can try to add a PNP output to my simulation to make a complementary drive (push -pull)... learning curve.. not hard.. just new for you, same base drive,  mirror image the loads.